# JCR (JackRabbit, ModeShape) vs. Graph (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, jackrabbit, jcr, modeshape

In order to store hierarchical data, can a graph database (Neo4j) be viewed as an alternative to JCR based solutions (ModeShape, JackRabbit)? Or do they belong to 2 different level of abstraction meaning that a JCR implementation could use Neo4j under the hood?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Both, people are building CMS applications with Neo4j as storage backend (see http://structr.org)

A JCR implementation could also be done using Neo4j, some people worked on that in the past, we also have a group using Neo4j as backend storage for Apache Shindig.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to take a look at OrientDB (http://www.orientdb.org/) which combines features of a Graph-DB (as Neo4j) with those of a Document-DB. There even seems to be a prototype implementation using OrientDB as a storage-adapter for Jackrabbit (https://github.com/eiswind/jackrabbit-orient) that illustrates the implementation of such a hybrid approach.